# Knockoutjs custom binding to display loading gif

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, custom-binding

I'm trying to create a custom binding that will show a loading gif while content is loading.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.loader = {
    init: function (element) {
        $('<div>').addClass('loader').hide().appendTo($(element));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var isLoading = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var $element = $(element);
        var $children = $element.children(':not(.loader)');
        var $loader = $(element).find('.loader');

        if(isLoading) {
            $children.stop(true).css('visibility', 'hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $loader.stop().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $loader.stop(true).fadeOut(function () {
                $children.css('visibility', 'visible').removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        }
    }
};
```

I can see in the init that `div.loader` is being appended to the `element`, and can see the update function fire when `isLoading` is changed to true. But once the images have loaded (by loaded i mean each image returns a resolved promise on the their respective load event) I don't see the update firing once `isLoading` is set back to false.

**viewModel**

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.movies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.searchValue = ko.observable();
    self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);

    self.search = function () {
        self.isLoading = true;
        $.getJSON(arguments[0].action, { name: this.searchValue() }, function (data) {
            self.movies(data);
            $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
                setThumbnailHeight(function () {
                    self.isLoading = false;
                });
            });
        });
    }; 
    var setThumbnailHeight = function(callback) {
        var $items = $('.thumbnails li');
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $items.map(function () {
            return $(this).innerHeight();
        }).get());
        $items.css('height', maxHeight);
        callback();
    };

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

`setThumbnailHeight` is being called at the correct time (once all promises have resolved) and is working properly, in that I see it setting the height of each `li` to the max height and can see the callback (in this case `function(){ self.isLoading = false; }`  being called.

**my binding**

```
<ul class="content thumbnails" data-bind="foreach: movies, loader: $root.isLoading">
    <li class="movie">
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

So just to recap, the problem is that the loading gif will be displayed when `isLoading` is set to true but is not hiding and showing the newly loaded content when it's set back to false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All observables are function so you cannot assign value to it using `=`. Use `self.isLoading(true);` instead of `self.isLoading = true;`

```
self.search = function () {
    self.isLoading(true);
    $.getJSON(arguments[0].action, { name: this.searchValue() }, function (data) {
        self.movies(data);
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            setThumbnailHeight(function () {
                self.isLoading(false);
            });
        });
    });
};

function(){ self.isLoading(false); }
```